# How to extract a text list from the Windows Program and Features?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

From the Windows Program and Features manage screen(above) I want to create a text file that contains all installed programs:

[image]

How can I automate this work?

I'm thinking about some script that would read some registry keys and put the results into a txt file, any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

Powershell:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Sort-Object Name | Select Name,version,Vendor |export-csv myprogramlist.csv
```

WMIC:

```
wmic product get name,version,vendor >myprograms.txt
```

Comment: Just be aware that the Win32_Product class which both of these solutions rely on only registers the install information for products that install via the Microsoft Installer service (MSI). On the other hand, every product that is listed in the Add/Remove programs and features applet have a registry entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one line solution in PowerShell based on the comment from EBGreen above:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | % { $displayName = $_.GetValue("DisplayName"); if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($displayName)) { $displayName } } | Sort-Object | Out-File ./InstalledPrograms.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [check this article](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2012/10/how-to-copy-list-of-program-installed.html). There might be an option. You can take a snapshot of the page and convert that to text. The article explains it in details.

Update 1: You can also take help of WMI product class to export all programs to csv. WMI product class contains the details about install apps. Using select * you can fetch data from there and store in csv. Read this example to know how to [export control panel to csv](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2013/06/easily-export-all-installed-apps-from.html).

Note: I am the developer of this script

Comment: While it's nice to have a link to credit your sources, you should provide some amount of details in case the link breaks.  Typically, just a link will earn downvotes.

Comment: Hello @Mamuni, your Script appears to having been hosted on Dropbox, which refuses to serve the file